# Textarea for my web application

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I am developing an application web based which would let the users extend a part of an applcation using javascript via java.scripting
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html

The problem is that the user should write only some coditions and i want if possible to colour some special words and to check while typing if the variable that the user is typing exists.. Like a auto suggest thing...
I searched at the web but didnt find many stuff.
For WYSIWYG editors i couldnt determine if you can programaticcaly apply stuff and set/get caret position.
Also i show that autosuggest is nearly impossible. It should be locatted outside of the textbox area.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to bite off a bit more than you probably want to chew. Designing a full-fledged JavaScript IDE is no simple task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look into adapting [ECCO](http://ecco.sourceforge.net/) into your project. I've not used it, but it looks amazing.